# Issues compiling hunspell from source on windows

Tags: mingw, mingw32, hunspell

Hi I am trying to compile a python module called hunspell from the following [source](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/hunspell).

But I get the following error message.

```
C:\Users\KURO\Desktop\hunspell-0.1>setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'hunspell' extension
C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -mdll -O -Wall -D_LINUX -I/usr/include/hunspell
 -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC -c hunspell.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.
7\Release\hunspell.o -Wall
writing build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hunspell.def
C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -mno-cygwin -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hun
spell.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\hunspell.def -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Py
thon27\PCbuild\amd64 -lhunspell-1.2 -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win-amd64-
2.7\hunspell.pyd
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.3.3/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot fin
d -lhunspell-1.2
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I tried downloading libhunspell-1.2-0.dll and put it into my system. But I still get the same error message. How do I deal with this? I have Windows 7 and [mingw](http://www.develer.com/oss/GccWinBinaries)